# Xamarin Studio : LaunchScreen.storyboard does not exists

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard

Can anyone tell me what this error is :

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets:
>   Error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/simonlam/Desktop/Pro/iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/build-iphone5.4-9.3/ibtool/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/01J-lp-oVM-view-Ze5-6b-2t3.nib does not exist File name:

In my solution, I can see my LaunchScreen.storyboard file but how come it said File not found.

Answer (score 2):

Basically renaming a viewcontroller caused me this problem,

**Cleaning** in Xamarin project was not enough. I had to delete **obj** and **bin** folders

I had to remove manually because **clean** command does not remove every temp file that was generated

[image: Obj bin]

Comment: I'm trying to use it, but Xamarin is not yet a reliable development system. Today it works, tomorrow you get an update and you can not even compile for a week! Quite distant from Microsoft standards

Comment: @tedebus - Yeah I also felt the same and its not completely stable as far as iOS part of Xamarin is concerned but Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Windows are not as buggy as iOS is though